# Trying to return the row if sentence is present in pandas dataframe with index value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have one dataframe. I'm implementing sentence transformers and returning one row based on the search query. For example

```
search_string = "thor's weapon"
search_vect = model.encode([search_string])
K = 3 # no. of paragraphs that has to be extracted
distilbert_similar_indexes = find_similar(search_vect, embeddings_distilbert, K)
print(distilbert_similar_indexes)
```

The output is :

```
array([7, 6, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Code followed by :

```
output_data = []
for index in distilbert_similar_indexes:
    output_data.append(paragraph[index])
print(output_data[0])
```

The output is :

```
'Stormbreaker is an enchanted axe used by Thor. It was forged from Uru on Nidavellir, and can summon the Bifrost.'
```

**Now i want to search the above sentence from the given dataframe and want to return the single row with that sentence and all given sentences. For example if i have dataframe like**

```
Sentences                                                Tag
0   Thor Odinson is the Asgardian God of Thunder, ...    Excel 1
1   Upon being welcomed back to Asgard as a hero, ...    Excel 1
2   Thor returned to Asgard having defeated his br...    Excel 2
3   Loki Laufeyson was the biological son of Laufe...    Excel 1
4   Stormbreaker is an enchanted axe used by Thor....    Excel 3
```

**Now i want to return the below row**

```
4   Stormbreaker is an enchanted axe used by Thor....    Excel 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
slice = df[df["Sentences"].str.contains(output_data[0])]

print(slice)
# Outputs
4   Stormbreaker is an enchanted axe used by Thor....    Excel 3
```